# TeamCity Dependency not sticking around

Tags: teamcity

I'm sure this is a dumb mistake on my part but I can't find the right answer.

I have a project that has a snapshot dependency on another project.  For sake of discussion website is dependent on toolkit.

Monitoring the build folder:
c:\programs\Teamcity\buildagent\work

I see the toolkit get built and the folders all exist as expected:
c:\programs\teamcity\buildagent\work\toolkit

Then the website build kicks off and the folder above gets deleted before the website build starts.

This results in the website saying the reference couldn't be found.  What setting am I missing?

Using TeamCity 7.1.2, working on getting it upgraded to 8.1 but it requires some internal evaluation first.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its a version issue. How do both of your builds know where to put the artefacts at . For ex teamcity normally builds stuff at c:\programs\teamcity\buildagent\work****\toolkit , not at c:\programs\teamcity\buildagent\work\toolkit ?

Also, if your targets are dependent upon each other across builds, (1) have you setup any artefact dependencies or  (2) any process that does not read of a shared agent workspace ? or (3) forcing both builds to run from the same directory

See if both your builds are running on the same target "folder name". In case they are , deselect any option that "cleans up build targets" before they run.

Also, you might want to check your build files to see if they have any code to clean directories before they start to run

Comment: I see nothing that is cleaning up files, set by me.  It says that Teamcity may clean up the directory before a build but no idea what triggers that. The file paths are different.  Toolkit goes to <root>/toolkit, web goes to <root>/website